# Are there faster ways for collecting all text nodes than using NodeIterator?

Tags: javascript, performance, iterator, dom-traversal, textnode

The **goal** is to collect all text nodes that are direct or indirect ancestors of the body element that meet certain criteria.
The **problem** is that collecting nodes via the method `nextNode` of a `NodeIterator` object seems really slow.

I did some performance tests, the first group with a `NodeIterator` that accepts all text nodes, in the second group nodes are accepted only if 3 criteria are being met.
The first group is about 3 times faster than the second one - but it is still too slow for my purpose.

```
const iterator = window.document.createNodeIterator(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    {
        acceptNode(node) {
            return (satisfies1(node) && satisfies2(node) && satisfies3(node))
        }
    },
    false);

const matchingTextNodes = [];
let n;

while (n = iterator.nextNode()) matchingTextNodes.push(n);
```

Are there faster alternatives to NodeIterators for this szenario?
I'm only interested in text nodes.

**Update:** Manually traversing the DOM seems slightly faster, still not a sufficient improvement thogh:

```
const matchingTextNodes = [];

function collect(el) {
    const children = el.childNodes;
    let c = children.length, child;

    for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        child = children[i];
        if (satisfies1(child) && satisfies2(child) && satisfies3(child)) {
            matchingTextNodes.push(child);
        } else {
            collect(child);
        }
     }
}
collect(document.body);
```

Comment: How big is your document? What's the overall goal? Maybe iterating the DOM is the wrong way if you need to meet performance criteria.

Comment: Questions about working code with performance considerations are better asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Bergi the document can be any website there is. The code is part of a browser extension. There is no way around collecting all text nodes (that meet the criteria)

Comment: @user1521685 Why do you feel that there is no way around collecting all text nodes? What does the browser extension do with them? How often is the `collect` function called, and what are you filtering for?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for trying to help:) It's actually not a feeling but more like knowing. all the text nodes are relevant. The nodes array is being used for multiple purposes, the filters are (roughly): 1) does the note contain text other than whitespace, tabs etc. 2) nodeName filter for its parent node (some of those are being rejected), 3) this can be left out actually. `collect` will be called at least 3 times but 2-digit of times is possible too. after each call text passages get wrapped by new elements which changes the text node collection.

Comment: I'm tending to manually update the text node array after each time I wrap text with an element: <body>foo bar</body> ~> wrap ~> <body>foo <span>bar</span></body> There are 2 text nodes now and instead of doing a new traversal I could update the text nodes array manually. It's a bit complicated though, since I need more than just a list of text nodes, but that's basically the way to go, I think